# Losing connection during a fetch causes crash in React-Native app

Tags: react-native, fetch

If the internet connection is lost during a fetch in my react-native app I get `Network request failed` and the app crashes.

```
  updateClientData() {

    var cachedData = null;

    AsyncStorage.getItem('cachedData').then((cachedDataString) => {  
       cachedData = JSON.parse(cachedDataString);     
    })

    .done(() => {

      if (cachedData) {
        const base64 = require('base-64');
        return fetch('https://...data.json', {
          method: 'get',
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic '+base64.encode("..."),
          }
        })

        .then( (response) => {
          // never called:
          return response.json();
        })

        .catch( (error) => {
          //Shouldn't this catch network errors? It never gets called.
          console.log('caught network error');
        })

        .then( (responseJSON) => {
            //do something with the JSON
        })

      } 

    });

  },
```

I would love to be able to handle this gracefully rather than have it crash. Any ideas?

Comment: What about moving the catch call to bottom most instead of putting it in between two then calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, moving the `AsyncStorage` call out of this function made it work fine. I didn't actually need it until I had the result of the fetch anyway, so I moved it.

This works now:

```
 updateClientData() {    

      const base64 = require('base-64');

      return fetch(clientListURL, {
        method: 'get',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Basic '+base64.encode("..."),
        }
      })

      .then( (response) => {
        return response.json();
      })

      .catch( (error) => {
        console.log('error...')
      })

      .then( (responseJSON) => {
        // now do something with the JSON and the data from Async Storage
    }

  },
```